# Problema usando una clase PHP al consumir un webservice SOAP

Tags: php, laravel, soap, laravel-9

buenas tardes estimados compañeros, tengo un problema con PHP, estoy trabajando en 2 clases: ClienteSiat.php y ServicioFacturacionCodigos.php las cuales deseo integrarlas como tal a un proyecto de laravel 9:

**ClienteSiat.php** es solo un enlace para el servicio SOAP que quiero consumir, y en **ServicioFacturacionCodigos.php** quiero usar a Cliente Siat como un objeto asignado en una variabe, pasar los parametros necesarios y que me de un resultad; si realizo pruebas desde el mismo ClienteSiat.php todo esta bien, me permite llamare a los metodos del SOAP.

Pero si trato de usar a ClienteSiat.php desde ServicioFacturacionCodigos.php, y ejecuto una prueba rapida desde ese archivo, me da el siguiente error:

> "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "App\Http\Controllers\Cliente" not found in /home/jose/projects/project1/app/Http/Controllers/Servicio.php:13".

La linea mencionada es cuando trato de crear un objeto a partir de ClienteSiat.php y guardarlo en una variable (en ServicioFacturacionCodigos.php).

Yo pensé que era problemas de permisos, quizá de la misma biblioteca de clientSoap... pero no es eso..... intente haciéndome un par de clases sin casi nada de funcionalidad que me sirva, solo a modo de prueba de que una clase use a otra, pero tengo el mismo error.
(Mis pruebas las ejecuto desde terminal  como    php miclase.php    )

Este es mi cliente de prueba:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


    class Cliente 
    {
        public string $endpoint1;
        public string $token1;
        public $connector;
        public function __construct(string $endpoint,string $token=""){
            $this->endpoint1=$endpoint;
            if($token!=""){
                $this->token1="apikey: TokenApi ".$token;
            }else{
                $this->token1="";
            }
        }
    }
```

y esta es mi otra clase de prueba:

```
<?php
namespace App\Soap;
use App\Soap\ClientSiat;
class ServicioFacturacionCodigos
{
    public $linkSiat;
    public string $endp, $etok;
    public function __construct($epoint,$etoken=""){
        var_dump($epoint);
        var_dump($etoken);
        $this->endp=$epoint;
        $this->etok=$etoken;
        $this->linkSiat=new ClientSiat($this->endp, $this->etok);
        
    }
    //functions calls of module to soapservice
    public function initClient(){
       
    }
}

//s$var=new ServicioFacturacionCodigos("asdf","asdfasd");



$d1="https://myservicesoap/service?wsdl";
$d2="eyJ0xxxxxxxxxxxxxdWw5ug8ew";
$cli2=new ClientSiat($d1,$d2);
$cli2->initClient();
//var_dump($cliente->getStatusConnection());
//$data=$cli2->connector->verificarComunicacion();
//$data=$cli2->getStatusConnection();
//var_dump($data);
//var_dump($cli2->getElementHeaderResponse("date"));
```

Estoy desde el dia viernes pataleando en este asunto, no doy con una solución, intente con composer dump, auto, auto load, vaciando cache etc, y nada.....

Mi entorno: ubuntu20.04, php 8.1.3, laravel 9.x

Comment: Parece un problema de namespace. ¿Que tienes en la línea 13 de app/Http/Controllers/Servicio.php?

Comment: $this->linkSiat=new ClientSiat($this->endp, $this->etok);

Comment: Fijate que tus clases cumplan con el standard [psr-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/). No le veo sentido a que el mensaje de error diga que el problema está en app/Http/Controllers/Servicio cuando la clase se llama ServicioFacturacionCodigos. Y también que diga App\Http\Controllers\Cliente not found, cuando estás instanciando una clase que se llama ClientSiat